# Dismissing ViewController after a time interval?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

Is there a way, that I can present or dismiss my ViewController after a time of 5 seconds? Maybe like...If the user presses a button after 5 seconds the new view appears.

Any solutions or suggestions? Sorry but I didn't found a solution on the web.

My code which doesnt work:

```
    -(IBAction)lol:(id)sender {

    [self performSelector:@selector(dissMissviewController) withObject:self afterDelay:3];
}

-(void)dissMissViewController{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below one..

```
//for dismissing the ViewControler on clicking button just use below piece of code.

[self performSelector:@selector(dismissViewController) withObject:self afterDelay:5];

//dismissviewController is the method which has the code for dismissing the viewController.

//and can follow the same for showing the viewController.

 - (void)dismissViewController
 {
 //if you are pushing your viewControler, then use below single line code
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 //if you are presnting ViewController modally. then use below code
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

I hope it may clears to you...!!!

Comment: I got this error:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController dissMissviewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2083d170'

Comment: @NoahRaissi it mea you should define that method for using ,as i said you have defined that method for using it...!!!is that clear.so please declare it in some where in your same class

Comment: sorry I'm a newbie cold you make an example for me?

Comment: Ohh...well I implemented it in the didFailedWithError method but it still gives me this error

Comment: OHH AAhh Sorry my mistake I understood sorry thank you very much ! :D

Comment: it doesn't seems to work I get the same error..look at my code above

Comment: @NoahRaissi it can't happen,ok so let me know one thing how you are showing this ViewController.can you send me your code...can you come on chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19493/dissmissgroup11222

Comment: OMG I found my mistake and you should correc  it too! Look at the spelling of dissMissviewController and in the method dissMissViewController...that was my mistake it works fine now. Thank you

Comment: `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` is depreciated in iOS 6, you should be using `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle it means it can be remove in future , here i just gave the logic .`- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^)(void))completion` is right one ..

Answer (score 0):

As you want that a new viewController is presented or dismissed after a delay of 5sec when a button is pressed, try implementing the below code

```
       -(IBAction)btnpressed:(id)sender
       {
          [self performSelector:@selector(dismissVC) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];

          //dismissVC is the method which has the code for dismissing the viewController. same is the case for presenting a ViewController by passing a selector which has the code for presenting the viewController

       }
```

Hope this helps.